# How to process FLT_MAX in GLSL for Vulkan

Tags: vulkan, spir-v

I have an algorithm which I try to implement in GLSL for Vulkan. That algorithm uses `FLT_MAX`.

Now I could define that to an arbitrary high float value but I really would be interested in how to actually e.g. process that value on runtime in GLSL.

Comment: which algorithm? FLT_MAX is a valid and non-infinite float value, so it's fine to use in spir-v

Comment: So... what problem have you had with using this value? What operations do you want to do with such values?

Comment: @NicolBolas I am currently writing the shader and am mostly wondering whether using a hardcoded `FLTX_MAX` will work on all Vulkan devices out there. Is there any guarantee, that a Vulkan device does not use 31bits instead of e.g. 32? So no problems as of now but want to know which guarantees I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vulkan shaders are required to support single-precision IEEE-754 representation, with a few exceptions detailed in the [Vulkan SPIR-V environment spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#spirvenv-precision-operation). So FLT_MAX should work the way you expect it to in C/C++.